# Amazon-MWS didn't handle our Requests. [ No Error, No Throttling ]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

We are hosting an application with 30 Users. Every 10 minutes we send an`_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_` Request. And we look it up every 4 minutes if it is finished. Before Friday all gone well. We even looked them up every two minute. And had the result in less then 10 minutes. Now (since Friday) we have to wait much more than one hour. We didnt change anything. There is no error and there should be no throttling? Could it may have do to something with the shut down of the AWS API? So everyone switched to MWS?
Amazon MWS Support ist to slow, they do not answer us, that's why we where looking for help, from other users. Do you have similiar problems since friday?
What could be the cause for this?

P.S. we are using the PHP library.
We looked up the ReportRequestList with MWS Scratchpad. The Requests got succesfull deliverd. So Problem only is, that Amazon now took so long tho process the ReportRequest.

Like Robert said, after exactly one week the problem is gone. There is nothing you can do against ( if there is, plese let me know ;) ), so stay cool if this happens to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately MWS can take some time to generate reports. This is normal behavior in my experiences.

As for AWS - AWS and MWS are entirely different API's and serve different purposes. So one should not affect the other.

You may want to see if another report would meet your purposes - for instance would `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_LITE_` or `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_LITE_` work for your purposes? Returning less columns may help with the report generation speed.

Aside from that the only other thing is to plan some sort of contingency for these eventualities as they will happen again.

Keep in mind that we are entering the busy season with the holidays - Reports will likely take alot longer to generate then normal.

--Edit--

I just generated our orders report and it took 5 minutes to go from `_SUBMITTED_` to `_IN_PROGRESS_` and 1 minute to go from `_IN_PROGRESS_` to `_DONE_`. Do you know which state is causing the delay?

Comment: Hi Robert.  
Unfortunately the `_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_` Report is the only one who can fullfill our requriements. But with 4 columns it is one of the smaller Reports.  
The delay get caused by going from `_SUBMITTED_` to `_IN_PROGRESS_`. `_IN_PROGRESS_` to `_DONE_` is usually fast.
But it looks, that other Report Types, get handled much faster, as i can see with the scratchpad. I will test now, if the `_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_` Report will proceed faster if i send with the Scratchpad.

Comment: @MichaelHirn I would expect that the issue is not with the method that the report is being requested, but rather with Amazon generating the report in question. I'm interested to see what your testing finds.

Comment: I tested a few things. 1) Requests of any typ get handeld slowly. And it does not matter if i send them with the PHP library or from scratchpad. 2) Changing the application name neither changing the MWS Endpoint from https://mws.amazonservices.de to https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com has any positiv effect. I really cant understand this behavior.

Comment: Like I said, unfortunately its normal, the last time we had an issue with the API it  lasted close to a week. I'm using the US end points and its slow here as well. Hopefully they resolve the issue sooner rather then later this time.

Comment: Do you have a special plan in your programm, when this is happening? Do you try some different strategy, to get your required information?

Comment: Because the issue is with Amazon there isn't much you can do code wise to speed things up. In my case I sped up how frequently I check for `_DONE_` and I download the report as soon as its returned. However, for our needs we download the reports in off hours (2am EDT) where ever possible and our on demand reports are far and few between. That being said, if your needs are more realtime inventory status checks and you need to have point in time inventory results you may have to put in a business process to support these delays.

Comment: Allright, i will check if i can optimize the programm. Thanks Robert for your help.